# Javascript - Create functions with variable name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create some functions based on variable names, something along the lines of:

```
var functionsToRegister = ["foo","bar"];

var index;
for (index = 0; index < functionsToRegister.length; ++index) {
    var function_name = functionsToRegister[index];

    PART_IM_MISSING = new Function('return alert("hello, world!");');
}
```

The client code calls specific methods so for example it will call `foo()`

Please note that I am not working on a website but on a native windows application (SoftOne) that allows some customization options through a javascript engine.

Also there is absolutely no way to change the client code calling the functions.

Comment: Would using an object/array not work? `functions[function_name]`

Comment: Generate an object with the corresponding keys?

Comment: @evolutionxbox @LPK would that allow client code to just run `foo()` or would it need to be called as functions["foo"]? Only the former would work.

Comment: The client code would need to run `functions.foo()`

Comment: @evolutionxbox this is absolutely impossible in this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var functionsToRegister = ["foo","bar"];

var index;
for (index = 0; index < functionsToRegister.length; ++index) {
    var function_name = functionsToRegister[index];

    this[function_name]=function() {
        return alert("hello, world!");
    }
}
```

This will add functions foo and bar to the this object (or you can use any object like `window`),

but I guess you don't want n identical functions.. so maybe:

```js
var functionsToRegister = {
    'foo':function() {return alert("hello, foo!");},
    "bar":function() {return alert("hello, bar!");},
};


var index;
for (index in functionsToRegister) if(functionsToRegister.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
    var function_name = index;
    var function_code = functionsToRegister[index];


    this[function_name]=function_code;
}


this['foo']();
this.bar();

foo();
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox sure it would! Updated snippet.

Comment: @evolutionxbox amd if you are in a browser and use `window`, also `foo()` would work

Comment: @FrancescoMM thank you for your time. In the context of this problem sadly the client can only call `foo()` so this will not work here.

Comment: @anpel That just plain works, provided the client refers to the same global object. Updated snippet.

Comment: @anpel In a global function, in a browser, `this` and `window` are the same. so `bar()` `window.bar()` and `this.bar()` are the same. But, as it was not specified if this code would run in a browser, `this` is safer. `window` may not be available (for example in node.js)

Comment: @FrancescoMM if I was in a normal browser window I would be a happy man. Sadly, as mentioned in the question "I am not working on a website but on a native windows application that allows customization options through a javascript engine. "

Comment: @anpel Then using `this` should work. Unless the client code and your function creation code run in two different contexts

Comment: @FrancescoMM `this` ended up being the way to do it. the window object was indeed not available. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the window object, to make a global function.

```js
var functionsToRegister = ["foo", "bar"],
    index,
    function_name;

for (index = 0; index < functionsToRegister.length; ++index) {
    function_name = functionsToRegister[index];
    window[function_name] = new Function('return alert("hello, world!");');
}

foo();
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reponse. Sadly, after testing it I found that the window object is not defined. Is there any way to work around that?

Comment: please add the platform.

Comment: @anpel - The "*window object is not defined*"? What platform are you running? Not a browser me thinks.

Comment: @evolutionxbox indeed. As I mentioned it the question it is a windows application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval.

```
eval('var '+name+'=function(){alert("hello");};');
```